# Managed Context from CoreDataStack isn't persisting through the navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to get a contacts page set up where I can add/edit contacts.
However, I'm getting a nil value when I try to call my CoreDataStack.context.

Here it originates in the AppDelegate

```
lazy var coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = navigationMainColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = navigationMainItemColor

    let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let listViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! ViewController
    listViewController.coreDataStack = coreDataStack

    return true
}
```

I pass it to my first view controller and inside the rootViewController I have a button that sends me to another view controller. In the rootViewController the CoreDataStack context is still there when I call print(coreDataStack). So I know it exists in the first view. The button I press to go to the contacts page is a bar button on a toolbar.

Possible problem 1 may be that I'm not moving to and from with the navigation bar, however all the views are embedded in a navigation stack.

Do I need to prepareForSegue inside the first view controller in order to pass the NSManagedObjectContext?

There is also a navigation controller between contacts and new contact view controller. But the nil seems to be returned before that even occurs.
In the contacts view controller the prepareForSegue that checks if the user is trying to add a contact is found here

```
else if segue.identifier == "AddContact" {
        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let addViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! NewContactViewController
        let contactEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)

        let newContact = Contact(entity: contactEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)

        addViewController.contact = newContact
        addViewController.context = newContact.managedObjectContext
        addViewController.delegate = self
    }
```

And the error I am getting is that the coreDataStack.context when I try and create a new contact is returning nil. I've been chugging away at this for hours and hours and I think I'm missing something really small or big. Either way I just want to learn Core Data and get better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to prepareForSegue inside the first view controller in order to pass the NSManagedObjectContext?

Yes, this is exactly the problem you are having.  You need to do your dependency injection yourself since Apple cannot predict where you want things :)

If your incoming (destination) view controller is wrapped in a navigation controller you can safely *assume* that point that the `topViewController` is your view controller (and you can test this) and inject it.

> So simply get the navigation controller and then get the destination controller? Is it simply a matter of destinationcontroller.context = self.context in the prepareforsegue for the first view controller?

The other way round:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let destinationNavController = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController else {
        print("Unexpected view controller: \(seque.destinationViewController.self)")
    }
    guard let myViewController = destinationNavController.topViewController as? MyViewController else {
        print("Unexpected view controller: \(destinationNavController.topViewController.self)")
    }
    myViewController.context = context
}
```

Replace pieces with your class names as needed.

> Yeah I figured, now I'm getting an odd error that I can't force downcast my ContactViewController to UINavigationController. Is it possible that my ContactViewController isn't on the navigation stack?

ok, step back.  If you are just pop'ing view controllers in a nav stack then you are getting your `ContactViewController` directly as the destination and you can skip the nav controller like this:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let myViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MyViewController else {
        print("Unexpected view controller: \(destinationNavController.topViewController.self)")
    }
    myViewController.context = context
}
```

If the segue is pointing to a **NEW** `UINavigationController` then there is something else wrong.

Comment: So simply get the navigation controller and then get the destination controller? Is it simply a matter of destinationcontroller.context = self.context in the prepareforsegue for the first view controller?

Comment: Answer updated to demonstrate what I am referring to.

Comment: Oh so this prepareforsegue is in the second view controller where its a receiving type of prepareforsegue. Awesome, thanks

Comment: This should be implemented in each view controller as you transition from one "scene" to another.  That way you are always passing down the information needed (in this case the context).

Comment: I guess I'm confused if the prepareforsegue that contains this information should be in the rootViewController or the one I am trying to push the context to.?

Comment: You put the `prepareForSegue` in the parent view controller and it will fire as part of the segue to the child (aka destination) view controller.

Comment: Yeah I figured, now I'm getting an odd error that I can't force downcast my ContactViewController to UINavigationController. Is it possible that my ContactViewController isn't on the navigation stack?

Comment: Then you don't have a nav controller in the middle.  See my update.

Comment: Yeah I realized that shortly after and changed it to what you had. I've been checking everything trying to make sure it's changing anything. I don't know if it's even saving to the CoreDataStack. I'm looking at the read/write in debug window and nothing is changing. The context is successfully being passed around add it goes so far as to call context.save() all the way in CoreDataStack.swift but alas no contacts in the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Your coredatastack should be singleton  class object. Now a days if you create a new coredata application Apple itself creates the plumbing code for you in AppDelegate. Since AppDelegate is a singleton class, you can access the coredatastack as AppDelegate.coredatastack anywhere in your application.
Since you have also defined the coredatastack in Appdelegate you don't have to pass it in your viewcontrollers, it can be directly accessed using

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate 
delegate.coredatastack
```

Comment: Singletons really should **NOT** be used in this situation or any other.  Apple's template is a very poor example and does not suggest creating  singleton.  In addition, your answer is not going to help the OP solve the actual problem.

Comment: The ques states that coredatastack context is not persisting. Coredata context should be singleton object. Apple and all other tutorial are based on that only. Apple itself create it as singleton in AppDelegate by default now.

Comment: Incorrect.  Apple's template demonstrated the creation of the Core Data stack in the AppDelegate.  First, the AppDelegate is **NOT** a singleton.  Just because there is one instance of an object does not mean it is a singleton.  Second, the template from Apple is a *poor* example of how to implement this stack and is old code.  You can verify this by reviewing the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) which was updated in March of this year.

Comment: Interesting. I will check that out.